# If $f$ and $f − g$ are integrable on $[a, b]$, then $|g|$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-writing

First post here, might be missing something I should have. Looking for some help, I'm not too certain on where to begin, missed a bit of math class so I'm catching up relatively quickly but I'm still a bit shaky.

Is this is a true statement and if it is, could someone help me with a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f-g$ is integrable so $g-f = -(f-g)$ is also integrable. $f$ is integrable so $f+(g-f)$ is also integrable, that is, $g$ is integrable.

Now, try to prove that if $g$ is integrable then so is $|g|$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can take it from here, I just didn't see how to prove that g itself is integrable for whatever reason.